# Prometheus scraping the same metric multiple times

Tags: prometheus, metrics

Hi I am new to prometheus and trying to migrate from graphite by using graphite-exporter to not make code changes at the moment. When I send a metric to test with as below it is appearing 5 times for the same labels in prometheus but it should only be 1, what could be the issue?

```
PORT=9109
SERVER=graphite-tcp.domain
echo "some.project.staging.action.failed 1 `date +%s`" | nc -w 5 ${SERVER} ${PORT}
```

[prometheus ui showing multiples of a metric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VXTA.png)

Comment: It looks like there us a metric which is using vector of `[1m]` or any other range. So you see the vector at each row. Here is the prometheus function https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate but you have to find this metric in your project

Comment: Take a look at VictoriaMetrics - it is compatible with Prometheus, while it supports data ingestion via Graphite ptotocol - see [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#how-to-send-data-from-graphite-compatible-agents-such-as-statsd). Note that Prometheus and VictoriaMetrics return calculated dataponts by default - see https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness . If you need exact samples, then see https://valyala.medium.com/analyzing-prometheus-data-with-external-tools-5f3e5e147639

Comment: @Felipe Thanks :facepalm:  I was using something like sum(sum_over_time(metric_name[5m]))  but all i wanted was sum all the metric values in last 5 minutes  i don't know if there is an easy way to  achive that.